# Detecting Elastic Beanstalk Environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to tag error messages by elastic beanstalk environment. Is there a way to programmatically determine what environment I am in from an EC2 instance inside the elastic beanstalk?

I am using ruby on rails so a ruby way would be nice, but I can port from any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a rails project and this is what we are currently doing inside in order to determine which environment our ec2 instance is a part of.

Below the code is doing more than one check, the file check makes sure that you are running this code on an ec2 instance. The second set of url calls are grabbing the ec2 instance id along with which aws region is being used. Then finally it uses the previous two pieces of data to find the environment-name using the aws-sdk. It's a little ugly but it gets the job done.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'aws-sdk'

uuid = File.readlines('/sys/hypervisor/uuid', 'r')
if uuid
    str = uuid.first.slice(0,3)
    if str == 'ec2'
        metadata_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/'
        dynamic_endpoint = 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/'
        instance_id = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( metadata_endpoint + 'instance-id' ) )
        document = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse( dynamic_endpoint + 'instance-identity/document') )
        parsed_document = JSON.parse(document)
        region = parsed_document['region']
        ec2 = AWS::EC2::Client.new(region: region)
        ec2.describe_instances({instance_ids:[instance_id]}).reservation_set[0].instances_set[0].tag_set.each do |tag|
            if tag.key == 'elasticbeanstalk:environment-name'
                @env_name = tag.value
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: As a note since you are not passing a block to `File.open` the file will not automatically close. Why not something like `File.readlines('/sys/hypervisor/uuid').first` this way it will self close otherwise you need to call `uuid.close` somewhere to make sure this isn't held indefinitely.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I made the change and it seems to work quite well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing you should be focus on **application environment** name and not on its sourroundings **elastic beanstalk environment** name. So use [elastic beanstalk environment variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html), set sth like APP_ENV, and read it programmatically in whatever lagnuage you are using inside your app.

It is kind of the same principle like with Object Oriented Programming where you encapsulate your stuff to be independent from ther rest of the code. Internals of EB may change with next release, elastic beanstalk environment variables will be still there...

Comment: Not necessarily, beanstalk lets you define the following hierarchy:

application> Environment 1, Environment 2 

Example:

my_blog > qa-environment-of-my-blog, prod-environment-of-my-blog

I think the OP wants to know if the instance is running in qa or prod from inside the instance

Comment: It sounds to me like checking if you drive your own car by checking VIN number on its engine when on highway ;)